# Why is casting to float give me so many digits which are not there in the first place?

Tags: kdb

So
I start with : 9.638554216867471

I have this code :

```
{[x;noOfDigits]
  x:string x; 

  if[null wIsDot:first ss[x;"."];:"F"$x];

  noOfChars:min(noOfDigits + 1 + wIsDot;count x);

  "F"$noOfChars#x 
  }
```

I expect to get this : 9.63

But I get : 9.630000000000001

"F"$"9.63" always gives  9.630000000000001

Comment: Your function references an undefined variable `noOfDigits`

Comment: forgot to add the params

Comment: What are you intending to do with your function? Truncate (i.e. round towards 0) the input number to `noOfDigits` decimal places?

Comment: basically let the user input a number of digits he wants after the dot 
mostly used for displaying purposes. 
I have read a bit around and it seems that it doesn't work. 
a solution would be to cast floats to symbol to keep their format

Comment: Your problems seems to be more related to the fundamental nature of floating point numbers, you can't always have a float which displays exactly how you like (and in any case such a display depends on the display precision `\P` that you've set. Ultimately if you want something to have a pretty display you should use strings, not floats.

Comment: More general discussion of this problem on [KX Community](https://community.kx.com/t5/New-kdb-q-users-question-forum/Five-easy-pieces-2-getting-around/td-p/11990)

Answer (score 3):

In kdb the final digit in a floating point number is notoriously unreliable, you can read about it here:

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/precision/

Just to give an idea, with \P set to 0 you get:

```
q)"F"$"9.63"
9.6300000000000008
q)9.63="F"$"9.63"
1b
```

So there is nothing wrong with your code, its just a quirk to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

There are various built-in functions you can use if the end goal is just to pretty-print numbers to specified decimal places:

```
q)update prettyPrint:-27!(2i;floats) from ([]floats:9.63 1.2345678)
floats   prettyPrint
--------------------
9.63     "9.63"
1.234568 "1.23"
```

Other built-in functions are `.Q.f` and `.Q.fmt` but the newer `-27!` might be preferable

Comment: hey. thank you very much for this. 
yes. my problem was related to casting to float from string for certain numbers which messed up the monitoring dashboard we're using. Decided not to use floats instead.

Comment: Avoid [internal functions](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/internal/) unless you need them – see warning on the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

Simple ways to cast a float to a string:

```
q)q:9.638554216867471
q)string .01 xbar q          / truncate
"9.63"
q)string .01*floor .5+100*q  / round
"9.64"
```

Functional alternatives to your original:

```
q)ft:{[x;nd]string(10 xexp neg nd)xbar x}  / truncate
q)ft[q;2]
"9.63"
q)fr:{[x;nd]string%[;s]floor .5+x*s:10 xexp nd}  / round
q)fr[q;2]
"9.64"
```